# Problems installing Yesod for Haskell

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm trying to install Haskell and Yesod for Mac [following this guide](http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart). Everything goes fine until the last step, when I receive this error message. I've tried to manually install the `hfsevebts-0.1.4` but it gives me the same error.

```
gcc-4.8: error: language objective-c not recognized
gcc-4.8: error: language objective-c not recognized
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
fsnotify-0.0.11 depends on hfsevents-0.1.4 which failed to install.
hfsevents-0.1.4 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
yesod-bin-1.2.3.4 depends on hfsevents-0.1.4 which failed to install.
```

How shall I proceed in order to install Yesod?

Comment: what system are you on (OS X 10.9, 10.8.x) ?

Answer (score 2):

I think this fixed it for me:

```
   $ brew uninstall gcc48
   $ brew install gcc48 --enable-all-languages
```

Presumably the default gcc48 doesn't include Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into that same error—among many others—trying to install yesod on 10.8.5. I had some luck uninstalling the package from Haskell and installing Haskell via Homebrew. I did upgrade to 10.9 and everything still works (but I had to re-install Xcode command line tools)

I documented [installing yesod on os x](http://www.jaydorsey.com/installing-yesod-on-os-x/) on my site if you need details.

Comment: I see you're using gcc4.8. If you're on os x 10.9, you can also patch it with https://gist.github.com/mzero/7245290 to handle the current clang/gcc mess with xcode 5.