# Objective-C not recognized building hfsevents with stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

If I start up a new project, add `hfsevents` to the list of dependencies in the `.cabal` file, and run `stack build`, I get an error (on Mac OSX Yosemite):

```
--  While building package hfsevents-0.1.6 using:
/Users/Me/.stack/setup-exe-cache/setup-Simple-Cabal-1.22.4.0-x86_64-osx-ghc-7.10.2 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.4.0/ build --ghc-options -hpcdir .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.4.0/hpc/.hpc/ -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file
Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
Logs have been written to: /Users/Me/Desktop/code/haskell/test/.stack-work/logs/hfsevents-0.1.6.log

Configuring hfsevents-0.1.6...
Building hfsevents-0.1.6...
Preprocessing library hfsevents-0.1.6...
[1 of 1] Compiling System.OSX.FSEvents ( System/OSX/FSEvents.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.4.0/build/System/OSX/FSEvents.o )
gcc: error: language objective-c not recognized
gcc: error: language objective-c not recognized
```

I already followed the advice of calling [`brew install gcc48 --with-all-languages`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758766/problems-installing-yesod-for-haskell) and I uninstalled all Haskell versions, only using the `ghc` within `stack`. Xcode is on version 7.1.1. What else can I try to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Eventually got this working. The steps that led me to the solution are documented here: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1563

Basically, I had two different `gcc`'s installed, one in `/usr/bin/` installed by Xcode and one in `/usr/local/bin/` from somewhere I don't remember. `/usr/bin/gcc` was the one being used by `cabal`, so `cabal install hfsevents` worked, while `/usr/local/bin/gcc`, which was the one apparently being used by `stack`, had this issue. What I did to resolve this was delete `/usr/local/bin/gcc` and only keep `/usr/bin/gcc`.

Comment: For posterity, could you include the relevant parts of the link which you found useful in your answer? That way, if the link goes down, changes, etc., your answer won't be rendered useless. Many thanks.

Comment: It works! My situation is similar. C (C++?) error `unknown type name 'instancetype` occured when building `hfsevents` package which is depended by `stack install hakyll` on macOS. There were `/usr/bin/gcc` (Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.2)) and `/usr/local/bin/gcc` (installed by Homebrew), so I `brew uninstall gcc`, then `stack install hakyll` succeeded.